# Creating a Dictionary with Line Numbers of Keywords

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to read through a txt.file and print the line numbers that keywords appear in. This is what I have so far:

```
def index(filename, word_lst):

    dic = {}
    line_count = 0

    for word in word_lst:
        dic[word] = 0

    with open(filename) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            line_count += 1
            for word in word_lst:
                if word in line:
                    dic[word] = line_count

    print(dic)
```

Output:

```
>>>{'mortal': 30, 'demon': 122, 'dying': 9, 'ghastly': 82, 'evil': 106, 'raven': 120, 'ghost': 9}
```

The above output is somewhat correct. The issue i am having is, for example, raven should print 44, 53, 55, 64, 78, 97, 104, 111, 118, 120 not just the last line number (120) that it appeared in.

I have been working on this problem for a solid day now, and i am not sure how to add all of the line numbers that the keyword appears in without overwriting the already stored line number in the dictionary.

I am new to Python so if it's something simple that i am missing i apologize and any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: that's what `dic[word] = line_count` do...

Comment: @njzk2 Yes, but that only shows the last line number that the word appears in, not all of the line numbers the word appears in. Like for raven, it should print the lines mentioned above, not just 120 like whats in the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To mapping multiple line number from words, you need to mapping to `list`, instead of `int`:

```
def index(filename, word_lst):

    dic = {}
    line_count = 0

    for word in word_lst:
        dic[word] = []   # <---

    with open(filename) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            line_count += 1
            for word in word_lst:
                if word in line:
                    dic[word].append(line_count)  # <----

    print(dic)
```

Comment: or even better `dic.setdefault(word,[]).append(..)` and `enumerate` infile

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) to accomplish the same. Something like:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def index(filename, word_lst):
    d = defaultdict(list)

    with open(filename) as f:
        for lineno, line in enumerate(f):
            for word in words:
                if word in line:
                    d[word].append(lineno)
```